# Passing strings from Delphi to Labview DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, labview

I have a simple Labview dll that takes a PascalString then returns the pascal string with no changes. This is just testing what we can do. The header is as follows:

```
void __stdcall Read_String_In_Write_String_Out(PStr String_input, 
    PStr String_output);
```

the Delphi code is as follows:

```
var
  hbar : thandle;
  str, str2 : PChar;
  StringFunction : function (TestString: PChar): PChar; stdcall;

begin
  hbar := LoadLibrary('C:\Interface.dll');
  if hbar >= 32 then begin
    StringFunction := getprocaddress(hbar, 'Read_String_In_Write_String_Out');
    str := 'test';
    str2 := StringFunction(str);
  end;
end;
```

When running the program i get an Access Violation. I have no issues when doing simple math functions using dll's, but when it comes to strings everything breaks.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your Delphi version? This will depend what type ``PChar`` actually really is: ``PAnsiChar`` or ``PWideChar``!

Comment: How's LabVIEW's ``PStr`` type defined? Is it a C-style 0-terminated string?

Comment: `void __stdcall Read_String_In_Write_String_Out(PStr String_input, 
    PStr String_output);` that looks more like `procedure(input, output: PChar); stdcall;`

Comment: @DelphiCoder The delphhi version is 10.3. I have tried both PAnsichar and Pwidechar to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the DLL function is taking in a Pascal String.  According to Labview's documentation:

> **Pascal String Pointer** is a pointer to the string, preceded by a length byte.

> **Pascal-Style Strings (PStr)**
> A Pascal-style string (PStr) is a series of unsigned characters. The value of the first character indicates the length of the string. A PStr can have a range of 0 to 255 characters. The following code is the type definition for a Pascal string.
>
> ```
> typedef uChar Str255[256], Str31[32], *StringPtr, **StringHandle;
> typedef uChar *PStr;
> ```

This would be equivalent to Delphi's `ShortString` type (well, more accurately, `PShortString`, ie a *pointer* to a `ShortString`).

Based on the DLL function's declaration, its 2nd parameter is not a return value, it is an input parameter taking in a pointer by value.  So your use of `StringFunction` is wrong on 2 counts:

- Getting the output in the wrong place. `StringFunction` should be a `procedure` with 2 parameters. However, the function can't modify the pointer in the 2nd parameter, all it can do is read/write data from/to whatever memory the pointer is pointing at. So, for output, you will have to pre-allocate memory for the function to write to.
- Passing around the wrong kind of string data. `PChar` is `PWideChar` in Delphi 2009+, but "Pascal strings" use `AnsiChar` instead.  And your test data is not even a Pascal string, as it lacks the leading length byte.

So, try something more like this instead:

```
var
  hbar : THandle;
  str1, str2 : ShortString;
  StringFunction : procedure (String_input, String_output: PShortString); stdcall;
begin
  hbar := LoadLibrary('C:\Interface.dll');
  if hbar >= 32 then
  begin
    StringFunction := GetProcAddress(hbar, 'Read_String_In_Write_String_Out');
    str1 := 'test';
    StringFunction(@str1, @str2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That at least gets me through the function without crashing now. Now it crashes with same error when trying to do anything with the str variable. for example if i just try to ShowMessage(Length(Str).ToString) it will crash with same error. Even though if i stop to debug and look at value of Length(Str) it will equal 5.

Comment: @ShawnVance so, is this working for you now? I seem to recall seeing a comment that it was, but that comment is now gone.